# Changing students level when session changes

Tags: python, django

I have a school management system website, and I want to change a student's level when the school year changes.

I don't know how to tackle this issue.

This is my student model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=LEVEL, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.get_full_name
```

This is my session table:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    session = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    is_current_session = models.BooleanField( default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    next_session_begins = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.session
```

These are the levels:

```
NCE_1 = "NCE I"
NCE_2 = "NCE II"
NCE_3 = "NCE III"
LEVEL = ( (NCE_1, "NCE I"), (NCE_2, "NCE II"), (NCE_3, "NCE III"), )
```

Comment: Please add those details to the question itself using *Edit*.

Answer (score 0):

You could override save method within Session model - if I got you task correctly.

```
class Session(models.Model):
   # your fields here
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Here is called the original Django actions that must be done on model save
        # Do what you need to with user
```

So once Session model has been saved it would trigger the changes you need to